# Show 3-colorable graph with hamiltonian cycle is NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete, reductions

The language is :
*$3COLORHC = \{<G> | \text{ G is an undirected 3-colorable graph that contains Hamiltonian cycle} \}$*
I was asked to show that this language is NP-Complete.
Showing that the language is in NP is easy, but I got stuck showing a reduction from an NP-Complete language.
I tried reducing from UHAMPATH problem but it seems like it won't work since for any complete graph $K_n$ where $n \geq 4$ there is a Hamiltonian cycle but the graph won't be 3-colorable.
I tried to think about a reduction from 3COLOR but I couldn't find a way to construct a Hamiltonian cycle from a 3-colorable graph.

Source: Open University of Israel

Comment: Show that recognizing bipartite Hamiltonian graph is NP-complete, that might be easier